# conjure-up on Ubuntu 17.04 ends in error

Tags: conjure-up

Running `conjure-up`, Canonical Kubernetes Distribution, Localhost ends with the following error:

```
Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ubuntui/ev.py", line 82, in run
    cls.loop.run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2])
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 126, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/ui/views/deploystatus.py", line 31, in _refresh_nodes_on_main_thread
    status = model_status()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 32, in _decorator
    login(force=True)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 123, in login
    uuid = get_model(app.current_controller, app.current_model)['model-uuid']
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 787, in get_model
    models = get_models(controller)['models']
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 858, in get_models
    "Unable to list models: {}".format(sh.stderr.decode('utf8')))
LookupError: Unable to list models: error: No controllers registered.
```

Please either create a new controller using `juju bootstrap` or connect to
another controller that you have been given access to using `juju register`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/bin/conjure-up", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conjure-up==2.1.5', 'console_scripts', 'conjure-up')()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/app.py", line 369, in main
    EventLoop.run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ubuntui/ev.py", line 82, in run
    cls.loop.run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1328, in run
    raise self._exc_info[0](self._exc_info[1]).with_traceback(self._exc_info[2])
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 126, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/ui/views/deploystatus.py", line 31, in _refresh_nodes_on_main_thread
    status = model_status()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 32, in _decorator
    login(force=True)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 123, in login
    uuid = get_model(app.current_controller, app.current_model)['model-uuid']
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 787, in get_model
    models = get_models(controller)['models']
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/juju.py", line 858, in get_models
    "Unable to list models: {}".format(sh.stderr.decode('utf8')))
LookupError: Unable to list models: error: No controllers registered.
```

Please either create a new controller using `juju bootstrap` or connect to
another controller that you have been given access to using `juju register`.

```
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x7f0d5c8a32b0 state=finished returned NoneType>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 297, in _invoke_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "/snap/conjure-up/197/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/deploystatus/gui.py", line 30, in __wait_for_applications
    relations_done_future.result()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'result'
```

Comment: Can you try the version from edge? `sudo snap refresh conjure-up --edge`

Comment: I had this problem and @gangstaluv provided the solution!